# File path of embedded resource?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resources

I've got some code which plays a WAV file via a DLL. It was playing it by pointing to a directory path, but I would like to include it in my EXE. So, I've put it as a resource. Problem is, how do I point to it correctly?

```
UInt32 stream = BASS.BASS_StreamCreateFile(Properties.Resources.MYWAVFILE, 0, 0, BASSFlag.BASS_DEFAULT | BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);
```

The original code had this:

```
UInt32 stream = BASS.BASS_StreamCreateFile(@"C:\MYWAVFILE.WAV", 0, 0, BASSFlag.BASS_DEFAULT | BASSFlag.BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);
```

You can see the first argument is where I need to put it. However, the compiler complains with this error:

*Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream' to 'string'   MyProgram   C:\Users\LOLCATS\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyProgram\MyProgram\Form1.cs 30  Active*

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Properties.Resources.MYWAVFILE` is not a path string. It's a representation of the file stored in memory, hence it's `System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream`.

Either find a overloaded function that takes in streams instead of file paths in `string` form or copy the embedded resource to disk and use it :

```
using (var fileStream = File.Create("C:\\Path\\To\\File"))
{
  Properties.Resources.MYWAVFILE.CopyTo(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to include it in the EXE itself. Can this be done?

Comment: My solution will _just work_ but what will probably happen is the embedded resource will get loaded into memory, it will get saved in a file (despite being loaded into memory already), and the function will read the file path, load the file in memory,  and do it's magic. So yes, finding a better library accepting a `Stream` would be better.. Try [`System.Media.SoundPlayer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx) instead using `new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.MYWAVFILE)`